# Google Maps API v3 - set bounds and center not working with Ajax/PHP

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the automatic bounds-and-zoom functions in Google Maps API 3 to work with Ajax/PHP-generated markers and having no luck so far. The PHP-gen map works fine (with manual center and zoom) until I add the bounds-related code, which I got from [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center). It now just centers at (0,0) in the middle of the ocean and only the first of my markers displays. The former doesn't seem totally surprising based on the initial `center` declaration of `(0,0)`, but it worked for the original poster and I'm a Javascript noob so don't really know what I'm doing! I would be eternally grateful if someone could spot the problem.

Here's my current code (I've left out the icon definitions to save space):

```js
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: '<?php echo $maptype; ?>'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("gen-xml.php?<?php if($country) echo "country=$country"; if($location) echo "&location=$location"; ?>", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("city");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
      var html = "<div class='infowindow'>" + name + " <br/>" + address + " <br/></div>";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bounds.extend(myLatLng);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }

  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
bounds.extend(point);
```

instead of

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
```

which seems not to be related to any part of your code

Comment: Thanks - you're right, that was a typo! But unfortunately it still doesn't work. Now instead of centering at (0,0) I get an all-gray background that doesn't zoom or move. Can you see any other problems?

Comment: @Holly: send me a link where I can have a look to your code. You can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to create a working example, then I'll have a look and try to figure out what's wrong

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure whether this helps, but this is how I've done it and it works a treat: After your var markers = xml line, add this: var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(); Then change your section that starts with bounds.extend and replace with: bounds.extend(point); map.fitBounds(bounds); bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html); This should work. Kind regards Chris