# Sencha rerender MapPanel

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a MapPanel and want to show a marker on the map. The map needs to wait on some data before rendering.

I'm loading som coordinates, and when they are loaded, I want the map to (re)render itself.

How is that possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you'd like the map to rerender itself completely. I think it would be enough for you to calculate the new bounds of your map, in order to fit all the markers on the map that you are loading.

In order to do this, see:
[Google Map API v3 — set bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I want to call a function in my MapPanel (the panel where I show the map), and in that function, the marker needs to be set. But it seems like I can't call the function, I get this error

"uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ superclass.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'updateMarker'"