# Store Map Bounds in DB for Google Maps API v3

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, bounds

Is there anyway to convert the bounds and/or center position to string and send it to the server side by json and store it?

I am asking because when I try to convert these stuff into string; I am getting conversion error from the api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `serialize` function, for retrieving map bounds and center data, then store it in DB.

```
function serialize(map){
    var json = '{"bounds":'+map.getBounds().toString() + 
               ',"center":'+map.getCenter().toString()+"}";

    //'toString' returns values in '()', we need to replace them by '[]'
    json = json.replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]");
    return json;
}
```

Use `deserialize` function, for updating map's state,by stored data:

```
function deserialize(map, json, useCenter ){
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    if( useCenter ){
        map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(json.center[0],json.center[1]) );
    }else{
        map.fitBounds( new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                      new google.maps.LatLng(json.bounds[0][0],json.bounds[0][1]),
                      new google.maps.LatLng(json.bounds[1][0],json.bounds[1][1])
                   ) );
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** `map.fitBounds` won't fit to exact bounds of its argument. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds).

Comment: This is not actually fits my scenario but definitely a correct and working answer. Thank you mate!