# Google Static Maps Dimension Discrepancy

Tags: google-maps, static

I've been using the code shown in the answer to this question:

[Google Maps V3 - How to calculate the zoom level for a given bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds)

but I can't seem to get my static maps to line up correctly.

In this link, I can calculate the width correctly, but not the height.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=30.42997,-91.179745&zoom=11&size=500x600&scale=1&format=png32&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false

From the SO post earlier, the height should be

`size * 360 / 256 / 2^Zoom`

so we plug in...

`600 * 360 / 256 / 2^11 = 0.41199`

This means that we expect top latitude of the image to be at `30.42997 + (0.41199 / 2) = 30.63596`. But when you plot that latitude on Google Maps and zoom to the same zoom level, the point is much higher than what our image is receiving.

Any ideas on how I can calculate the height of the image that Google is sending back?

Comment: I am wondering this as well. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are 180 degrees in latitude, not 360, so the height calculation shall be

```
height * 180 / 256 / 2^Zoom
```