# Calculate Zoom Level for Google Map for two LatLong values

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap` in `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

XML code is this :

```
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dip" />
```

`int zoomLevel =` ? // How I can calculate the zoom level for two diffrent latlong values
as android map v3 need to tell zoom level as int

```
map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
```

I have start and destination values as `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

LatLng start , end;

I am adding a pligon like `GoogleLocation.addPolyLineOnGMap(mMap, startPoint, endPoint, startMarker, endMarker)`

My problem is how I can calculate zoom level for Google map so it can show both marker appropriately on map.

Comment: Google Maps for Android has a V2 up to now, not V3 (V3 is for JavaScript). What do you mean by "calculate zoom level"?

Comment: Please use proper English and be specific about the issue

Comment: From the code (GeoPoint) it looks like Google Maps API V1.

Answer (score 17):

Use LatLngBounds.Builder add all the bounds in it and build it, Then create the CameraUpdate object and pass the bounds in it updatefactory with padding. Use this CameraUpdate object to animate the map camera.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker m : markers) {
            builder.include(m.getPosition());
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = ((width * 10) / 100); // offset from edges of the map
                                            // in pixels
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,
                padding);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, i need to calculate the zoom for initial map setup by `GoogleMapOptions`, so using `LatLngBounds.Builder`
would not work and not optimized. This is how I calculate the zoom based on a city's northeast and southwest coordinates

It's referencing [here](http://luan-itworld.blogspot.hk/2013/07/calculate-google-map-zoom-level-on.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055653/2369266), you can simply put the code below to your helper class:

```
final static int GLOBE_WIDTH = 256; // a constant in Google's map projection
final static int ZOOM_MAX = 21;

public static int getBoundsZoomLevel(LatLng northeast,LatLng southwest,
                                     int width, int height) {
    double latFraction = (latRad(northeast.latitude) - latRad(southwest.latitude)) / Math.PI;
    double lngDiff = northeast.longitude - southwest.longitude;
    double lngFraction = ((lngDiff < 0) ? (lngDiff + 360) : lngDiff) / 360;
    double latZoom = zoom(height, GLOBE_WIDTH, latFraction);
    double lngZoom = zoom(width, GLOBE_WIDTH, lngFraction);
    double zoom = Math.min(Math.min(latZoom, lngZoom),ZOOM_MAX);
    return (int)(zoom);
}
private static double latRad(double lat) {
    double sin = Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180);
    double radX2 = Math.log((1 + sin) / (1 - sin)) / 2;
    return Math.max(Math.min(radX2, Math.PI), -Math.PI) / 2;
}
private static double zoom(double mapPx, double worldPx, double fraction) {
    final double LN2 = .693147180559945309417;
    return (Math.log(mapPx / worldPx / fraction) / LN2);
}
```

Creating `LatLng` simply by `new LatLng(lat-double, lng-double)`

`width` and `height` is the map layout size in pixels

Comment: Note: `width` and `height` need to be measured in density pixels, not plain pixels, or the zoom level will be incorrect on newer devices with higher-density screens.

Answer (score 1):

in Android:

```
LatLngBounds group = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include(tokio)   // LatLgn object1
                .include(sydney)  // LatLgn object2
                .build();

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(group, 100)); // Set Padding and that's all!
```