# Calculate viewport that fitBounds() return for given bounds and map size

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps-api-3, geometry, geospatial

I have a web application with a server side and client side component. I perform the same geocoding request on both sides using the Google Maps HTTP API and Google Maps Javascript API.

Both APIs responds with the same viewport for a given query, that's all fine and great.

My problem is that I use the method `map.fitBounds()` on the given viewport on the client side to zoom and pan the map to contain the viewport. The problem is that I would like to perform the same operation on the server side, to allow me to supply the client with the appropriate data as soon as possible.

The current approach is to render the map on the client side and then send the **actual viewport of the rendered map** to the server to perform the calculations. My goal is to remove this step and perform the calculations before the client side even has started rendering the map.

[This JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cakuhaca/1/edit?html,js,output), show what I'm talking about, in `Bounds 1` and `Bounds 3`. When `fitBounds()` is called, the map is zoomed to the highest possible level that still contains all of the rectangle (and according to my research an additional 45 px margin around the bound).

The geographical coordinates for this **actual viewport** is what I'm looking for.

In this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds/13274361#13274361), [John-S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/859640/john-s) gives a method to calculate the highest possible zoom level for a map in a given dimension.

I think this should be possible to modify to fit my needs, but I'm not sure how, my mercator projection skills are sadly lacking.

The function should take a bound (`sw`, `ne` coordinate pair) and a size of the map div and return the geographical bound that `map.fitBounds` would return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally arrived at this code, based on the linked answer, which provide functionality to calculate zoom levels and appropriate view ports.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, atan2, sqrt, pow, pi, log, floor, tan, atan, exp


class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, lat, lng):
        """
        Represents a coordinate with decimal latitude and longitude in degrees
        :type lat: float
        :type lng: float
        """
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng

    def in_rectangle(self, box):
        """
        :param box: Box
        :return: True or False
        """
        return (box.south_west.lat <= self.lat <= box.north_east.lat) and \
               (box.south_west.lng <= self.lng <= box.north_east.lng)

    def distance_to_coordinate(self, another_coordinate):
        # convert decimal degrees to radians
        """
        Calculates the distance between the coordinate and the supplied coordinate. Based on the Haversine formula.
        Returns the value in meters.
        :param another_coordinate: Coordinate
        :return: float
        """
        lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [self.lng, self.lat, another_coordinate.lng, another_coordinate.lat])
        # haversine formula
        delta_lon = lon2 - lon1
        delta_lat = lat2 - lat1
        a = sin(delta_lat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(delta_lon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
        km = 6378100 * c
        return km


class Box(object):
    def __init__(self, south_west, north_east):
        """
        Represents a rectangle on the sphere with the south west and north east corners.
        :type north_east: Coordinate
        :type south_west: Coordinate
        """
        self.north_east = north_east
        self.south_west = south_west

    def center(self):
        """
        Calculates the center point of the box
        :rtype : Coordinate
        """
        lat_center = self.south_west.lat + (self.north_east.lat-self.south_west.lat)/2
        lng_center = self.south_west.lng + (self.north_east.lng-self.south_west.lng)/2
        return Coordinate(lat_center, lng_center)


def max_zoom_level_to_fit_box_in_element(box, element_width, element_height):
    """
    Calculates the maximum zoom level that would fit box in a map element with the specified width and height
    :type box: Box
    :type element_height: float
    :type element_width: float
    """
    WORLD_HEIGHT = 256
    WORLD_WIDTH = 256
    ZOOM_MAX = 21
    ne = box.north_east
    sw = box.south_west

    lat_fraction = (_lat_to_rad(ne.lat) - _lat_to_rad(sw.lat)) / pi
    lng_delta = ne.lng - sw.lng
    lng_fraction = ((lng_delta+360) if lng_delta < 0 else lng_delta)/360

    lat_zoom = _zoom(element_height, WORLD_HEIGHT, lat_fraction)
    lng_zoom = _zoom(element_width, WORLD_WIDTH, lng_fraction)

    return min(lat_zoom, lng_zoom, ZOOM_MAX)


def viewport_for_box_in_element(box, element_width, element_height, zoom):
    """
    Calculates the viewport, rectangle, which will fit box within it for a given map size and zoom level.
    The return value is a box, with coordinates on the sphere.
    :param box: Box
    :param element_width: float
    :param element_height: float
    :param zoom: float
    :return: Box
    """
    center_x, center_y = _lat_and_lng_to_x_and_y_for_zoom(box.center().lat, box.center().lng, zoom)

    viewport_sw_x, viewport_sw_y = center_x - element_width/2, center_y+element_height/2
    viewport_ne_x, viewport_ne_y = center_x + element_width/2, center_y-element_height/2

    viewport_sw = _x_and_y_to_lat_and_lng_for_zoom(viewport_sw_x, viewport_sw_y, zoom)
    viewport_ne = _x_and_y_to_lat_and_lng_for_zoom(viewport_ne_x, viewport_ne_y, zoom)

    return Box(viewport_sw, viewport_ne)


def _lat_and_lng_to_x_and_y_for_zoom(lat, lng, zoom):
    """
    Converts decimal degree coordinates on the sphere to x and y points on the flat Web Mercator projection, for a
    given zoom level.
    :param lat: float
    :param lng: float
    :param zoom: float
    :return: x,y: float
    """
    lat_rad = lat * (pi/180)
    lng_rad = lng * (pi/180)
    x = (128/pi)*pow(2, zoom)*(lng_rad + pi)
    y = (128/pi)*pow(2, zoom)*(pi-log(tan(pi/4+lat_rad/2)))
    return x, y

def _x_and_y_to_lat_and_lng_for_zoom(x, y, zoom):
    """
    Converts x and y points on the flat Web Mercator projection, for a given zoom level, to decimal degrees on the
    spehere.
    :param x: float
    :param y: float
    :param zoom: float
    :return: Coordinate
    """
    lng_rad = (x*pi)/(pow(2, zoom)*128)-pi
    lat_rad = 2*atan(exp(pi-((y*pi)/(pow(2, zoom)*128))))-pi/2
    return Coordinate(lat_rad*(180/pi), lng_rad*(180/pi))

def _lat_to_rad(lat):
    """
    Converts a decimal degree latitude to radians, given the fact how Web Mercator projection wraps on the latitude.
    :param lat: float
    :return: float
    """
    _sin = sin(lat * pi / 180)
    rad_x2 = log((1 + _sin) / (1 - _sin)) / 2
    return max(min(rad_x2, pi), -pi) / 2

def _zoom(map_px, world_px, fraction):
    """
    Calculates a zoom level
    :param map_px: float
    :param world_px: float
    :param fraction: float
    :return:
    """
    ln_2 = log(2)
    return floor(log(map_px / world_px / fraction) / ln_2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try map.getBounds()? This will give you the current bounds. I think that is what you need.

Comment: Sorry if my post was not clear enough. I want to get the bounds on the server side, i.e where I don't have access to the map and therefore cannot run `map.getBounds()`. Your approach is how I do it today (and send the current bounds to the server), but the goal is to perform it server side to improve loading times.