# Google Maps API setBounds to exact coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the Google Maps API it allows you to set the bounds of a map given a list of coordinates. That's awesome. My issue is that it gives a little bit of breathing room on the sides. I'm trying to get the bounding box I'm looking at to be barely containing the bounds.

For example, I want to view California so I set the bounds to be the Northeast and Southwest corners. Instead of showing just California though, I get all of Oregon and half of Mexico.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
var geo_region = {
    northeast: {
        lat: 42.0095169
        lng: -114.131211
    }
    southwest: {
        lat: 32.528832
        lng: -124.482003
    }
}
var map_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
map_bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(geo_region.northeast.lat, geo_region.northeast.lng));
map_bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(geo_region.southwest.lat, geo_region.southwest.lng));

var plot_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
plot_map.fitBounds(map_bounds);
```

EDIT:
A clearer example might be Wyoming since it's such a nice rectangle. If my map dimensions are the same ratio as Wyoming, I only want it to show me Wyoming.

EDIT:
Somebody suggested that I offset the bounds manually so I grabbed some data on the offsets that Google is using but I can't figure out what their formula is for deciding those offsets so I'm a long ways away from being able to do that. I even used the viewport coordinates from Google's Geocoding API but those didn't help much either.

Here's my data: https://docs.google.com/a/dovidev.com/spreadsheets/d/1HZLdDt5uiGwEtY0NbX0pfkmYVuUDndptm_-kzq0vh_w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: related question: [Google Maps V3 - How to calculate the zoom level for a given bounds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048975/google-maps-v3-how-to-calculate-the-zoom-level-for-a-given-bounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done EXACTLY because of the way google's zoom level's work. Google sets the bounds of the area but zooms in as closely as possible without cutting anything out. Because the zoom levels are incremental and their increments are so large, this often means that you'll end up with a lot of extra space.

When I tried to zoom in even once from what I thought was grossly oversized, I found that parts of the bounds had been cut off.

And thus we see that Google is already getting it as tight as it can be.