# Making google maps move on a path

Tags: path, maps, move

I've got a website vith a view of a (long) street, with markers appearing all along it that have different information on them about that location.

What I'm trying to do is create a button so when you press it, it starts at the bottom of the street and slowly moves the map along the street, opening each pop-up as you go then closing it when the next one opens.

The markers are all generated using a php loop linked to a database of information and I'm using InfoBubble to create the pop-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the google function bounds.extend and fitBounds: [Google Map API v3 — set bounds and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center) and add some of your markers to the array and wait a bit and add new markers to the array and rinse and repeat. You can use a javascript timer to wait. Or you can save your path and use fitbounds only on that marker.

Edit: When you have the next bounds with getBounds you can calculate delta x and delta y, e.g. x2-x1 and y2-y1 from 2 points of the start bound and the target bound.

Comment: Thank You, this worked great after some complex php that made my head hurt.

Comment: If you come accross some code to my the map "flow" from marker to marker that would be useful also, instead of it jumping.