# Google maps - keep center when zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google Maps, I would like to be able to keep the center of the map on a marker on my location when I'm zooming in or out. It's something that Ingress does, it doesn't matter where you double tap (or double click) or where you pinch, the map remains centered on your marker. So it's possible...

The best I came up with for now is :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mymap, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    mymap.setCenter({lat: myLoc.lat, lng: myLoc.lon});
})
```

But it's far from perfect, it just re-center the map after the user already zoomed...

Thanks a lot !

[EDIT] absolutely nothing helps in the API ref... Or elsewhere I'm blind and missed it !

Comment: Try setting draggable to false on the map properties

Comment: Already set. That prevents from moving away, which is good, but not from zooming away...

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: No, sorry, I put it aside and worked on other things since I asked the question... Still hope someone would help on this.

Comment: I am not shure. Can you test it? var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(myLoc.lat, myLoc.lon); mymap.setCenter(latLng);

Comment: I think you could disable zoom and handle your self.

Answer (score 4):

Purely using **Javascript**

- First you disable scroll zoom function by default of google map by **scrollwheel=false**,
- Next create custom scroll zoom function by capture mouse event and set zoom level for google map

Check my sample code: Fiddle URL: https://jsfiddle.net/vh3gqop0/17/

```js
var map, i = 12;
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.769603, 23.589957);
  var mapOptions = {
   center: myLatlng,
   zoom: i,
   scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
   mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   map: map,
   title: 'Any Title'
  });


 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#map_canvas').on("wheel", function(evt){
   // console.log(evt.originalEvent.deltaY);
      if(evt.originalEvent.deltaY > 0){
         map.setZoom(++i);
        }else {
         map.setZoom(--i);
        }
      
    });
});
```

```css
#map_canvas{
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: although, when you try to zoom-in/out after dragging, the center gets changed. And so it doesn't work. It think you can turn off dragging by setting `draggable: false` in the map options. Updated your answer accordingly

Comment: This sample does not update the current zoom level, if you try to zoom using the UI controls it will not update the `i` and mess up the zooming.

Comment: @Erevald because of this sample code for my solution, I know that you have more case for this but my solution is core and any case you can show, try use my solution you can resolve :D.

Comment: Can you please post the answer as a Codepen/JSBin/Fiddle? [StackOverflow doesn't support running code snippets on the mobile site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293274/cant-run-stack-code-snippets-on-the-mobile-site), and the full site hijacks the pinch event.

Comment: I can't pinch zoom in Chrome on Android, even after maximizing the result pane in JSBin. Also, I can't pan the map, which is required.

Comment: I have captured by event scroll event mouse scroll. on android google map zoom by two fingers, I will update for this case soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why you tagged this question as both Javascript and Android. On Android you need to wrap your MapView inside another view and detect Double Tap motion inside `onInterceptTouchEvent` which you can override if your class can override `FrameLayout` for example. Then return true to prevent the map from handling this event and you handle it instead.

For full code please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118649/764897

Comment: Turns out the OP was looking for a JavaScript solution, so this answer unfortunately doesn't apply. I'm looking for a solution as well, so I'll put a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Google Maps Api does not provide this behaviour.

The following example doesn't require jQuery and supports double-click and mouse scrolling, but you can add more events if you want.

View in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/errvald/pen/mWoWBR)

Disable:

- Double-clickin
- Scrolling
- Panning

Add `dblclick` and `zoom_changed` events on the map and a `mousewheel` event on the canvas.

I have commented the code, hopefully this works for your case. Keep in mind that you need to normalize mousewheel speed for all browsers and devices. Hammer.js is a good library for that.

```js
var map, zoom;

function initialize() {

  // The white house!
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.8977, -77.0365);

  // Default zoom level
  zoom = 17;

  // Keep a reference for evens
  var $map = document.getElementById("map");

  // Disable scrolling + double-click + dragging
  map = new google.maps.Map($map, {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    //draggable: false
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map
  });


  // EVENTS

  // Double Click: event zoom by 1
  map.addListener('dblclick', function(e) {
    zoomHandler(e.latLng, 1);
  });

  // Zoom changed: update current zoom level
  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function(e) {
    // Using a timeout because `getZoom()` does not return a promise.
    setTimeout(function() {
      zoom = map.getZoom();
    }, 50);

  });

  // Dom event: On mousewheel
  $map.addEventListener('mousewheel', wheelEvent, true);
}

// Mouse Scrolling event
function wheelEvent(event) {
  if (event.deltaY > 1)
    zoomHandler(event, -1);
  else
    zoomHandler(event, 1);
}

// Zoom in/out
function zoomHandler(event, zoomin) {
  zoom += zoomin;
  map.setZoom(zoom);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC9d3jaUX6Qdr0Uzvq6fQXVmZ1PBuHEVAQ"></script>
```

Comment: Added a Codepen and mentioned about the need to normalize mousewheel speed and/or pinch events.

Comment: Tried the Codepen on Chrome 57 on Android, but I can't pinch-zoom or pan the map.

Comment: You can pan now, I don't have an android to test pinch-zoom at the moment but the code I posted shouldn't block the default behaviour. Like I said there needs to be a normalisation of values between different type of events to get a smooth experience.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the `center_changed` event with `panTo` function.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mymap, 'center_changed', function() {
    mymap.panTo({lat: myLoc.lat, lng: myLoc.lon});
})
```

You can see an example about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=en#EventListeners) and documentation about `panTo` function [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference).
**Becareful**, it should mess up all the *draggable thing*.

Comment: This sample will get endless loop .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll fix that `setCenter` to `panTo`; thanks for your response @HoangHieu