# Google Map mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using Google Map API V3 & for styling, I am using [Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/).
And I am using multiple markers for multiple locations.
Everything is good working fine I just want to show all the marker on the mobile screen right now one has to drag the screen with two fingers to locate the locations in mobile devices.

Is there any way to adjust zoom level for mobile devices?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
function initMap() {

var usa = {lat: 38.6318618, lng: -98.318221};
var pacificOcean= new google.maps.LatLng(39.964202, -130.271346);
var atlanticOcean= new google.maps.LatLng(37.391290, -58.478699);


var alabama = {
    info: '<p class="m_title">Alabama</p>\
                <p class="m_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>\
                <a class="m_link" href="#">Learn More</a>',
    lat: 32.806671,
    long: -86.791130
};

var utslRO = {
    info: '<p class="m_title">Utah RO</p>\
                <p class="m_desc">Lorem Ipsum</p>\
                <a class="m_link" href="#">Learn More</a>',
    lat: 40.7762691,
    long: -112.2006695
};

var utccRP = {
    info: '<p class="m_title">Utah RP</p>\
                <p class="m_desc">Lorem ipsum</p>\
                <a class="m_link" href="#">Learn More</a>',
    lat: 37.6848877,
    long: -113.1720903
};

var ohio = {
    info: '<p class="m_title">Ohio</p>\
                <p class="m_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</p>\
                <a class="m_link" href="#">Learn More</a>',
    lat: 40.388783,
    long: -82.764915
};

var locations = [
  [alabama.info, alabama.lat, alabama.long, 0],
  [utslRO.info, utslRO.lat, utslRO.long, 1],
  [utccRP.info, utccRP.lat, utccRP.long, 2],
  [ohio.info, ohio.lat, ohio.long, 3],
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4.2,
    center: usa,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(39.964202, -130.271346), google.maps.LatLng(37.391290, -58.478699)),


        draggable: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({


});

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon:'marker.png'
    });



    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i)); 
}
}
```

Comment: You need to setbounds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center

Comment: I have tried bound you can see in my code @LukeP.Issac

Comment: You need to get all the marker position which you are creating in the for loop, in a variable and then use map.fitBounds(variable), after the for loop ends. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556921/google-map-api-v3-set-bounds-and-center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out a simple JS trick here its

```
function initMap() {
  var zoomVal = 4.2;
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
    zoomVal = 2.5;
  }

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: zoomVal,
    center: usa,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });
}
```

It works perfectly on all mobile devices.